# I am trying to deploy my next.js project, but I keep getting the following error with everything I do:

Tags: next.js, vercel, dnd-kit

i tried to deleted **node_modules** folder and run
**npm install --legacy-peer-deps**
but it not helped for me can anyone help?

**Build Failed
Command "npm install" exited with 1**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-star-rating-component@1.4.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @dnd-kit/accessibility@3.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@dnd-kit/accessibility
npm ERR!     @dnd-kit/accessibility@"^3.0.0" from @dnd-kit/core@6.0.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/@dnd-kit/core
npm ERR!       peer @dnd-kit/core@"^6.0.6" from @dnd-kit/modifiers@6.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/@dnd-kit/modifiers
npm ERR!         @dnd-kit/modifiers@"^6.0.0" from sanity@3.10.1
npm ERR!         node_modules/sanity
npm ERR!       2 more (@dnd-kit/sortable, sanity)
npm ERR!   39 more (@dnd-kit/core, @dnd-kit/modifiers, @dnd-kit/sortable, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.2.0" from react-star-rating-component@1.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-star-rating-component
npm ERR!   react-star-rating-component@"^1.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.2.0" from react-star-rating-component@1.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-star-rating-component
npm ERR!     react-star-rating-component@"^1.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-05-11T07_42_14_610Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-05-11T07_42_14_610Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

Comment: Did you already try with yarn command 
`yarn`

Comment: show what do you have in ```"dependencies": {``` in package.json? It seems to be npm problem not dnd-kit